# $f(x)$ is irreducible if and only if $f(x)$ does not have a root in $\mathbb{Z}/\mathbb{2Z}.$

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-fields

> Let $f(x)$ be a polynomial in $(\mathbb{Z}/\mathbb{2Z})[x]$ of degree $2$ or $3$. Prove that $f(x)$ is irreducible if and only if $f(x)$ does not have a root in $\mathbb{Z}/\mathbb{2Z}.$

I know that $f(x)$ is irreducible if and only if $F[x]/(f(x))$ is a field.

Any suggestions/hints will be appreciated.

Comment: [abstract-algebra] is a tag best used with other tags; your latest questions have all been about finite fields. Why not add the [finite-fields] tag, then?

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Will do from now onwards. I didn't know that tag existed! I learned Abstract algebra from three different professors  (and books) since undergrad days, so I am confused about notations and conventions!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Having a root in the field of coefficients is equivalent to having a linear factor. If a polynomial of degree 2 or 3 factors in a non-trivial way, then at least one of the factors is linear.

Comment: I want to accept your answer but I don't understand it. I will need time to stare/think at(about)  your answer.

Comment: If $f(x)=(ax+b)g(x)$, with $a\neq0$ and $g(x)$ another polynomial, then $f(-b/a)=0$. If $a$ and $b$ are in some field, then so is $-b/a$.

Comment: Note that the field $\mathbf{Z} / 2 \mathbf{Z}$ has nothing to do with it. The proof over that field is exactly the same as the proof over $\mathbf{Q}$.

Comment: +1 to Hurkyl's comment. It is easier to check for presence of roots in $\mathbf{Z}/2\mathbf{Z}$ though :-)

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Thanks! I forgot this falls directly from a know result.