# Construction of multiplication and addition tables for GF(4) with Modulo ($x^2 + x + 1$)

Tags: modular-arithmetic, finite-fields

I am still trying to understand polynomial arithmetic with Galois Field.
Can someone explain to me what this question is asking to be constructed. I have searched all over google for GF(4) with modulo and I am not getting anywhere.

I have read over a few of the other posts here on the forums but none seem to apply to my specific situation. Can anyone help me understand GF with modulo of a polynomial?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: See also [this older question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1298684/11619). Close to being a duplicate actually.

Comment: I don't know if my answer was enough clear :(

Comment: @MonsieurGalois is GF(2) the same as GF(4)?

Comment: GF(2) is the finite group of 2 elements. To generate GF(4) you need to create an extension of GF(2) with a polynomial.

Answer (score 1):

What you're asking saying *$GF(4)$ modulo $x^2+x+1$* is equivalent to do:

$$GF(2)\cong \frac{\mathbb{F}_2[x]}{x^2+x+1}$$

So the sum of $GF(2)$ is the same as in $\mathbb{F}_2[x]$ and then doing the modulo $x^2+x+1$: Since all your elements of degree $2$ or greater can be reduced considering $x^n=x^2x^{n-2}=(x+1)x^{n-2}$, you only will have elements of degree $1$ or $0$, and this will be the table:

$$
\begin{array}{ | c | c | c |c| c|}
    \hline
     & \color{green}{0} & \color{green}{1} & \color{green}{x} & \color{green}{x+1}\\ \hline
     \color{green}{0} & 0 & 1 & x & x+1 \\ \hline
     \color{green}{1} & 1 & 0 & x+1 & x \\ \hline
     \color{green}{x} & x & x & 0 & 1\\ \hline
     \color{green}{x+1} & x+1 & x & 1 & 0\\ \hline
    \hline
  \end{array}$$

For the case of the multiplication, you can do it

$$
\begin{array}{ | c | c | c |c| c|}
    \hline
     & \color{green}{0} & \color{green}{1} & \color{green}{x} & \color{green}{x+1}\\ \hline
     \color{green}{0} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ \hline
     \color{green}{1} & 0 & 1 & x & x+1 \\ \hline
     \color{green}{x} & 0 & x & x+1 & 1\\ \hline
     \color{green}{x+1} & 0 & x+1 & 1 & x\\ \hline
    \hline
  \end{array}$$

Why? It's clear that $1\cdot a=a$ for any element or why $0\cdot a=0$, so let's see the case with $x+1$. Look that $(x+1)x=x^2+x$, but by your quotient, $x^2+x+1\equiv 0$, so $x^2+x\equiv 1$ (we're modulo 2), and by the same reason, $(x+1)^2=x^2+2x+1\equiv x^2+1\equiv x$ And that's the way the multiplication happens.