# Galois Field of order 4 operation with addition

Tags: field-theory, finite-fields

Before posting any answers to my question; just a little note that, I only know the name of this **such thing** but have no clue what it is, i.e. the Galois Field of order 4.

Also, I have looked at the other posts that might explain it but it doesn't really clear it up for me, because how I go about these things is by showing that it fails one of the axioms of a field by the use of corollaries and theorems.

Suppose that we have a finite-field $F = \{0,1,a,b\}$.

**Question:** How does $1+1 = 0$? 
I tried to think through in my head the other options and show that it can't be those other options, i.e. $1+1 \neq 1$ was the easy one.

$1+1 = 1 \implies 1 = 0$ but $1 \neq 0$ thus a contradiction.

I'm not sure how to go about how to show that $1+1 \neq x$?

Thanks.

Comment: You may find [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1298684/11619) helpful. Depends. What other algebraic structures have been covered up to this point? Groups? Rings?

Answer (score 1):

Under addition, $F$ is a group, and $1$ is a nonzero element. By Lagrange, it either has order $2$, i.e., $1+1=0$, or order $4$, and $F$ is cyclic. In the latter case
$F=\{0,1,1+1,1+1+1\}$ where $1+1+1+1=0$. Then consider $2=1+1\ne0$. What is $2\times 2$ in $F$?

Comment: This is too complex of an answer as where I am at in my math knowledge. Sorry can't understand it.