# Determinant of matrix with coefficients in field of 4 elements

Tags: abstract-algebra, determinant, finite-fields

I want to calculate the determinant of the matrix

$M=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1\\
x & y & z\\
x^2 & y^2 & z^2
\end{pmatrix}$

where $x,y,z\in\mathbb{F}_4=\{0,1,a,b\}$ (the field of four elements). $x,y,z$ could be distinct elements of $\mathbb{F}_4$ or not.

All I know is that for any element $\mathbb{F}_4$, say $t$, then $t+t=0$, that $b=a^2$ and that $+$ and $\cdot$ are commutative in $\mathbb{F}_4$. Because $t+t=0$, then $t=-t$ for all $t\in\mathbb{F}_4$. I have found that:

$\det{M}=1\cdot(y\cdot z^2-y^2\cdot z)-1\cdot(x\cdot z^2-z\cdot x^2)+1\cdot(x\cdot y^2-y\cdot x^2)$

Using $t=-t$ and the fact that $1\cdot t=t$ for all $t\in\mathbb{F}_4$, then we have:

$\det{M}=yz^2+zy^2+xz^2+zx^2+xy^2+yx^2$

Is there a way of simplifying things further?

Comment: Look up the formula for [Vandermonde](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde_matrix) determinant, and then compute it over $\mathbb{F}_4$.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: The formula for the Vandermonde determinant gives
$$
\det(M)=(x+y)(x+z)(y+z)
$$
over any field of characteristic $2$. Now use the addition and multiplication table for $\mathbb{F}_4=\{0,1,a,b\}$ (if you google MSE, then you will find it [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/172980/galois-field-gf4), or at other MSE-questions).

Comment: Alternatively [WA it](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Finite+field+order+4).

Comment: Yes, WA is very useful, indeed.