# What is the difference between $\Bbb F_4$ and $\Bbb Z/4\Bbb Z$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

And more generally what is he difference between $\Bbb F_n$ and $\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z$ when we look at them as rings with multiplication and addition? Aren’t the tables of multiplication and addition the same?

Comment: Do you mean "the" finite field of order 4?  Because $\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$ is not a field, so they're definitely different.

Comment: Yes sorry, I guess F is a field

Comment: They line up if and only if $n$ is a prime.

Comment: And how can it be a field if 2 has no multiplicative inverse?

Comment: It's not.  There IS a field of order 4, but it is not $\mathbb{Z}_4$.

Comment: Where do they not line up in this case where n=4?

Comment: So which field is it?

Comment: @StanislasHildebrandt There is a unique $\mathbb{F}_{4}$ up to isomorphism, and it is the [Galois Field GF(4)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/172980/galois-field-gf4).

Comment: You get it typically from forming a quotient of $\mathbb{Z}_2[x]$ modulo an irreducible quadratic.

Comment: @StanislasHildebrandt $ \mathbb{Z}_2[x]/(x^2+x+1) $ is the $  \mathbb{F}_4 $.

Comment: Groups and a field are *not* unique up to the number of elements.  You can have multiple different groups and a field with $n$ elements. $\mathbb Z_n$ is a finite cyclic group and is a field only if $n$ is prime.  $Z_4$ is not a field because $2*2 = 0$ which is a zero divisor and there is not inverse $a$ so that $2a = 1$.  $\mathbb F_4=\{0,1,a,b\}$ where $a+1=b;b+1=a$ and $a*a = b;a*b=1;b*b=a$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$ \mathbb{F}_4 $ means the finite field with $ 4 $ elements, but $ \mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z} $ is not a field, since $ \bar 2\times \bar2=\bar 0 $ in $ \mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z} $.

Generally, $ p $ is prime if and only if $ \mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z} $ is a field and the only field with $ p $ elements up to isomorphism. Otherwise, any finite field with $ q=p^r $ elements where $ r>1 $ is not isomorphic to the quotient ring of $ \mathbb{Z} $.

Answer (score 3):

$\mathbb{F}_n$ is typical notation for "the" finite field of $n$ elements.  It is a theorem that such a thing is unique up to isomorphism.  The notation $GF(n)$ is also used.  Also, $n$ must be a power of a prime $n=p^d$ so you may also see $GF(p^d)$.  (Consequence of another theorem:  $GF(p^d)$ is vector space of dimension $d$ over $\mathbb{Z}_p$.)

To your question, $\mathbb{Z}_p$ is a field when $p$ is prime, so by the uniqueness result, $GF(p)$ "is" $\mathbb{Z}_p$.  When $n$ is NOT prime, $\mathbb{Z}_n$ is certainly not a field, so it cannot be $GF(n)$.  To see this, if $n$ is not prime then $n = ab$ for integers $1< a< b <n$.  But then $[a][b]= [n] =[0]$ in $\mathbb{Z}_n$ so we have zero divisors.  Thus $\mathbb{Z}_n$ is not a field.

To get $GF(p^d)$ when $d > 1$ you need to know a good deal about ideal theory and polynomials.  There is a theorem that $\mathbb{Z}_p[x]/I$ is a field when $I$ is a maximal ideal in $\mathbb{Z}_p[x]$.  You then classify all such maximal ideals $I$ as the principals $I = (g(x))$ where $g(x)$ is irreducible.  A simple count then shows that $\mathbb{Z}_p[x]/I$ has order $p^d$ where $I = (g(x))$ and $g(x)$ has degree $d$.

Comment: Can you explain a little bit the last sentence please?

Comment: Well, it's a lot to bite off.  If the irreducible $g(x)$ has degree $d$ then every coset $f(x) +I$ of the quotient ring can be uniquely written--using long division---as $b_0 + b_1x + \cdots + b_{d-1}x^{d-1} + I$.  Now count up the number of ways to choose the coefficients and you get $p^d$ different cosets/elements.

Comment: I probably shouldn't've said it was a "simple" count.