# Irreducible polynomial of degree 3 in Z5

Tags: abstract-algebra, irreducible-polynomials

I am trying to find an irreducible polynomial of degree 3 in Z5 and then use that polynomial to construct a finite field.

I found that the polynomial $x^3 + x^2 + 1$ is irreducible in Z5 (since none of 0, 1, 2, 3,4 are roots). But I'm stuck on how to use that polynomial to construct a finite field.

Comment: wouldn't $-1 \equiv 4 \pmod{5}$ be a root?

Comment: Notice that $4^3 + 1 = 0$ in $\mathbb{Z}_5$. $x^3+1$ is not irreducible over $\mathbb{Z}_5$

Comment: @AdlerMarques thanks, I have edited my question

Comment: It looks like $1^3+1^2+1+2\equiv 0\mod 5$...

Comment: @abiessu I think x^3 + x^2 + 1 works

Comment: Um, but now you need to check $3$ and $4$, too...

Comment: @paulgarrett I have checked 3 and 4 and they aren't roots either, I forgot to type them above in the question

Comment: I am still stuck on constructing the finite field

Comment: [Here's an article I wrote about it in detail](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3660825/how-are-the-addition-and-multiplication-tables-for-gf4-constructed/3660966?r=SearchResults#3660966).

Comment: @MJD thanks, would the field be F5?

Comment: The field you'll get from a degree-3 irreducible polynomial will be $F_{5^3}$.